# Bind dynamically supplied methods to a certain object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Trying to make a little custom library for HTML5 Canvas (JavaScript) but can't figure out how to bind dynamic prototype methods for custom entity classes to the object that owns the prototype - instead, the methods are bound to the prototype object they're supplied in... for example:

```
var map = new Map({
  map: '#canvas'
});

var Rectangle = map.entity({
  name: 'Rectangle',
  constructor: function(x, y, width, height) {
    // Here, `this` refers to the instantiated object
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  },
  prototype: {
    moveTo: function(x, y) {
      // Here, `this` refers to the object containing this function - prototype
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  }
});
```

Object which contains #moveTo (prototype) is what `this` is bound to in #moveTo., but I want it to be bound to the object referred to in constructor.

Here's MapInstance#entity...

```
entity: function(name, constructor, prototype, supers) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(name) === '[object Object]') {
        name.supers = name.supers || {};
        this[name.name] = name.constructor || function() {};
        var p = name.prototype || name.constructor.prototype;
        for (var i = 0; i < name.supers.length; i++) {
            for (var m in name.supers[i].prototype) {
                p[m] = name.supers[i].prototype[m];
            }
        }
        name.constructor.prototype = p;
    } else {
        supers = supers || {};
        this[name] = constructor;
        var $p = prototype || constructor.prototype;
        for (var j = 0; j < supers.length; j++) {
            for (var f in supers[j].prototype) {
                $p[f] = supers[j].prototype[f];
            }
        }
        constructor.prototype = $p;
    }
    return name.constructor || constructor;
}
```

I tried p[m].bind(name.constructor) and $p[f].bind(constructor) on lines 9 and 19, respectively, but `this` still refers to the object holding the prototype methods.

How would I bind it to the value of `this` in the constructor function?

Comment: What are you trying to do?? overriding `prototype` and `constructor` is not a good idea...  Also you are calling `entity` with the argument `name` referencing the object with the properties `constructor`, `prototype`, and  `name` It just does not make sense to me. Guessing?? If you want inheritance use `Object.create`

Comment: Trying to let the user dynamically create classes as shown in the example. How am I overriding prototype and constructor? They're just arbitrary names here. As for that, it's to let the user call the function with either an object (name) or individual properties (name, constructor, prototype, supers).

Comment: It's really not very clear what you're asking.  I think the best thing you could add would be the use case you imagine should work, the desired outcome from it, and the current outcome from it.  You seem to have some of that in plain english, but it's not coming across clearly.  Use code!

Comment: using prototype in the object is redefining it `var foo = { prototype : blah }` redefines the prototypes of `foo` or for want of a better word "overrides" prototype

Comment: I never override it though, I just extend it with the prototypes of the supers, if given. Also, I edited my example (first snippet) with two comments to help explain what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Out of my league..Sorry, please disregard my comments.